# Why isn't javac finding the com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit package I am trying to import

Tags: java, classpath, htmlunit

I have downloaded the latest release of HtmlUnit (released on January 5, 2023), along with all of its dependencies, and put it in /opt/htmlunit_2.69.0

I have been, so far unsuccessfully, trying to import the com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.* packages from a Java program called ClassPathProblem.java.

Details below:

```
achab@HP-Envy [Navajo] $ls -la /opt/htmlunit_2.69.0/
total 17568
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root     4096 Jan 10 18:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root  root     4096 Jan 10 18:38 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   353793 Jan 11  2023 commons-codec-1.15.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   325983 Jan 11  2023 commons-io-2.10.0.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   587402 Jan 11  2023 commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root    61829 Jan 11  2023 commons-logging-1.2.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   316431 Jan 11  2023 commons-net-3.9.0.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   238400 Jan 11  2023 commons-text-1.10.0.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root    98115 Jan 11  2023 dec-0.1.2.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root  2162299 Jan 11  2023 htmlunit-2.69.0.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root  1346968 Jan 11  2023 htmlunit-core-js-2.69.0.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   212052 Jan 11  2023 htmlunit-cssparser-1.13.0.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   277131 Jan 11  2023 htmlunit-xpath-2.69.0.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   785639 Jan 11  2023 httpclient-4.5.14.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   327891 Jan 11  2023 httpcore-4.4.16.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root    41727 Jan 11  2023 httpmime-4.5.14.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 achab achab 8540386 Jan 10 18:34 jar_files.zip
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   327912 Jan 11  2023 jetty-client-9.4.50.v20221201.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   234753 Jan 11  2023 jetty-http-9.4.50.v20221201.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   183018 Jan 11  2023 jetty-io-9.4.50.v20221201.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   583157 Jan 11  2023 jetty-util-9.4.50.v20221201.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   541746 Jan 11  2023 neko-htmlunit-2.69.0.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root    65830 Jan 11  2023 salvation2-3.0.1.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root    52172 Jan 11  2023 websocket-api-9.4.50.v20221201.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root    45622 Jan 11  2023 websocket-client-9.4.50.v20221201.jar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   214633 Jan 11  2023 websocket-common-9.4.50.v20221201.jar
achab@HP-Envy [Navajo] $
achab@HP-Envy [Navajo] $
achab@HP-Envy [Navajo] $head ClassPathProblem.java 
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ClassPathProblem {
   
    public static void ClassPathProblem () {
       
        try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
achab@HP-Envy [Navajo] $
achab@HP-Envy [Navajo] $
achab@HP-Envy [Navajo] $javac -classpath ".;/opt/htmlunit_2.69.0/*"  ClassPathProblem.java 
ClassPathProblem.java:1: error: package com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit does not exist
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
```

javac returns more errors. But all or most of them are the consequence javac inability to find the HtmlUnit packages that I am trying to import.

What have I been doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The classpath separator on linux is `:`, not `;`:

```bash
javac -classpath '.:/opt/htmlunit_2.69.0/*' ClassPathProblem.java
```

Comment: Thank you very much R.Z. Witser Loot!!! ... That did fix the problem!!